# How can I use DelegateCommand correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf

In the debug mode, goes from constructor to the set method, but in the get method does not enter at any point, which I think is the problem, but I don't know how to solved.

In the .xaml file I defined the button.

```
<dx:ThemedWindow
    x:Class="ProductsModule.View.ProductView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    Title="MenuView" Height="800" Width="1000">
    
    <Grid Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Height="420" DataContext="{Binding Detail}">
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="1"/>
        </Grid.Effect>
        <StackPanel Margin="750 70 70 70" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="18" Margin="0 5" Foreground="#FF6A6A6A"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding ShowCommand }">Add data</Button>
            
        </StackPanel>
        
    </Grid>
    
</dx:ThemedWindow>
```

In .xaml.cs file I defined datacontext.

```
public SecondView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
```

VIEW MODEL

```
public ViewModel()
        {
            ShowCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowMethod);
        }
        public ICommand ShowCommand
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        private void ShowMethod()
        {
            OrderView orderView = new OrderView();
            orderView.Show();
        }
```

When I press the button, ShowMethod() is not called and does not do anything.

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint or debug.writeline to the showmethod and see if it fires or note?

Comment: Also if you can, could you post the complete xaml?

Comment: At quick glance everything looks correct, so mistake is elsewhere, please refer to [mcve]. Btw, don't define setter for property assigned in constructor. This way you will also exclude possibility of command being replaced (which could be your case)..

Comment: @sommmen In the debug mode, goes from constructor to the set method, but in the get method does not enter at any point

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding Detail}"` is the problem. Remove it and the button should work. You should have binding errors in Output window.